# Dialog that returns a value then destroys self without using helper functions in the calling class?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My program involves creating objects from entered data. If data is entered that might be incorrect but won't break the program (such as typos), the user is prompted with a dialog that warns of the errors and asks if they wish to proceed.

Very trimmed down code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Tab_ProjectDesigner:

    def __init__(self):    
        self.proceed = BooleanVar(self.page, False, "proceed")

        self.str_messages = StringVar(self.page, name="str_messages")
        #Contains information about possible errors, if any

        ##self.page is Frame containing all widgets in this class##

    def warning(self):
        #creates dialog warning user of possible errors before proceeding

        warningBox = WarningBox(self.page, self, self.str_messages.get())

    def createObject(self):
        #if errors present:
             self.warning()
        #if self.proceed.get() == True:
             #proceed to create object
        return

class WarningBox(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parentWidget, parentClass, warningText):
        super().__init__(parentWidget)

        self.proceed = parentClass.proceed

        lbl    = Label (self, text=warningText + "\nAre you sure you want to proceed?")
        btnYes = Button(self, text="Yes", command=self.true)
        btnNo  = Button(self, text="No",  command=self.false)

        return

    def true(self):
        self.proceed.set(True)
        self.destroy()
        return

    def false(self):
        self.proceed.set(False)
        self.destroy()
    return
```

**createObject()** calls **warning()** if possible errors are present. **warning()** creates **WarningBox**, which prompts user, and modifies **self.proceed** in **Tab_ProjectDesigner** instance it is called from. **WarningBox** then destroys itself.

The code works, but it got me wondering. Is there a way for WarningBox to handle its own behavior/events and then simply return a value to the function that created it? Like:

```
def warning(Self):
    #if erorrs:
        proceed = WarningBox():
    if proceed == True:
        #proceed to object creation
```

Answer (score 0):

A class can't return a value, it always returns an instance of the class.

What you *can* do is make your code wait until the dialog window is closed. Then, when you do `WarningBox(...).proceed`, first `WarningBox(...)` is executed, which only returns after the window is closed, then after the dialog is closed the `proceed` property is read, which is `True`, `False` or `None`, depending on how the dialog is closed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Tab_ProjectDesigner:

    def __init__(self):    
        self.page = Tk()

        self.str_messages = StringVar(self.page, name="str_messages")
        self.str_messages.set('test string')

        self.createObject()

        self.page.mainloop()

    def createObject(self):
        if WarningBox(self.page, self, self.str_messages.get()).proceed:
            print('Continue')
        else: 
            print('Stop')

class WarningBox(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parentWidget, parentClass, warningText):
        super().__init__(parentWidget)

        # Let the toplevel be transient:
        # A transient window is always drawn on top of its master,
        # and is automatically hidden when the master is iconified or withdrawn.
        # Under Windows, transient windows don’t show show up in the task bar.
        self.transient(parentWidget)

        # Set default value in case of closing the Toplevel instead of pciking an option
        self.proceed = None

        Label (self, text=warningText + "\nAre you sure you want to proceed?").pack()
        Button(self, text="Yes", command=self.true).pack()
        Button(self, text="No",  command=self.false).pack()

        # Route all events for this application to this widget
        self.grab_set()
        # wait until the Toplevel window is destroyed before returning
        self.wait_window(self)

    def true(self):
        self.proceed = True
        self.destroy()

    def false(self):
        self.proceed = False
        self.destroy()

Tab_ProjectDesigner()
```

---

P.S. I would strongly advise you to not use wildcard (`from ... import *`) imports for both tkinter and ttk. There are a lot of widgets in these modules with identical names, which can cause confusion about from which module a widget you are using comes.